# How to add comment and like function in Article Page in Classic Experience?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, like, social-comment

we have this requirement that our news article page need to have comment and like function and we are using SP online classic experience not modern experience which has that function in default.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Likes are the easy one, just enable it on the pages list in list settings. You have the choice between Likes and Ratings. As far as I remember comments will require a new custom page layout